# In Corda, how to share confidential identities between multiple parties?

Tags: corda

Let's say I have the following transaction:

- Four parties involved
- Each party wants to use a confidential identity
- Each party's confidential identity should be shared with the other three parties

Corda's `IdentitySyncFlow` only allows a party to send its confidential identities to other parties. It doesn't allow a party to send the confidential identities of other parties to a node.

How would I exchange confidential identities between all four parties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `IdentitySyncFlow` only allows a node to distribute its **own** confidential identities.

At this time, there are no library flows that support the pattern you describe. I have raised a JIRA for this: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-954.

In the meantime, you'd have to implement your own flow which emits the check on line 37 of the `IdentitySyncFlow` (https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V2/confidential-identities/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/confidential/IdentitySyncFlow.kt#L37):

```
val identityCertificates: Map<AbstractParty, PartyAndCertificate?> = extractOurConfidentialIdentities()
```

This line prevents the flow from distributing the confidential identities of other participants to the transaction.